# VBA project works fine on machine with outlook 2013, but not on a machine running outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

Both machines are running 64 bit versions of Win7. The project has been painfully pieced together, I am not a programmer.

The function of the project is to automatically search emails for attachments upon a reminder set to fire every night and only download attachments to specified pathway that have the string defined by the two "pos" lines of code. Basically it just checks if the file name contains the desired name/phrase. The files I am working with change slightly with every email and over the years, but always contains the one statement. If the mail was unRead, it marks it as read when it is done with all the attachments in each email.

The only other difference is the machine with outlook 2010 does have some other code running on it. I placed this code on the machine with outlook 2013 to see if it was conflicting, but it ran perfectly still.

The following code works beautifully on the machine with outlook 2013, but not at all on the machine with outlook 2010. The project compiles just fine, and "runs" but does not download any files nor mark any emails as unread.

Here is the code in "This Outlook Session"

```
Private WithEvents MyReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set MyReminders = GetOutlookApp.Reminders
End Sub

Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
' returns reference to native Application object
 Set GetOutlookApp = Outlook.Application
End Function

Private Sub MyReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If ReminderObject.Caption = "Daily Report" Then
    ReminderObject.Dismiss
    Daily_Report
End If


If ReminderObject.Caption = "Shutdown Outlook" Then
    ReminderObject.Dismiss
    Application.Quit
End If

ProgramExit:
 Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit

End Sub
```

And Here is the code I have on Module1, this is only because of the pre-existing code on the other machine. I know it doesnt have to be in the module. Here it is:

```
Sub Daily_Report()
' This Outlook macro checks a the Outlook Inbox for messages
' with attached files (of any type) and saves them to disk.
' NOTE: make sure the specified save folder exists before
' running the macro.
   On Error GoTo GetAttachment_err

' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileNameXLS As String
    Dim FileNamePDF As String
    Dim posXLS As Integer
    Dim posPDF As Integer

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
            ' Save any attachments found
             If Item.UnRead = True Then
             For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments

             posXLS = InStr(Atmt.FileName, "FINAL EXCEL")
             posPDF = InStr(Atmt.FileName, "Final PDF")

                        If posXLS <> 0 And (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".xls") Or posXLS <> 0 And (Right(Atmt.FileName, 5) = ".xlsx") Then
                            FileNameXLS = "C:\Users\ba\Downloads\Babcok Lab Reports\Babcock Excel\" & Atmt.FileName
                            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileNameXLS
                        End If

                        If posPDF <> 0 And (Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".pdf") Then
                            FileNamePDF = "C:\Users\ba\Downloads\Babcok Lab Reports\Babcock PDF\" & Atmt.FileName
                            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileNamePDF
                        End If

            Next Atmt
            Item.UnRead = False
        End If
    Next Item

' Clear memory
GetAttachment_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
' Handle errors
GetAttachment_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was looking at the Outlook Data File "Inbox" when all the mail was going into the gmail account Inbox that outlook was setup with. Once I redirected the mail into the "Data File Inbox" via an inbox "rule" the code worked beautifully. The Daily_Report subroutine is being invoked correctly and the application is being used properly. Alternatively, I probably could have redirected my code to look in the gmail inbox, but didn't know how to easily do this being an amateur in programming. Any suggestions for the alternate will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Application property in the code:

```
 Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
 ' returns reference to native Application object
    Set GetOutlookApp = Application
 End Function
```

Also I'd recommend debugging the code in the step-by-step manner. Nobody can help you until specify the exact error you get on the problematic machine.

> I am not a programmer

The current web site is for developers, that's why I'd suggest learning the basics at least. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx).

Make sure that the Daily_Report sub is invoked correctly.

Comment: When I run the VBA on outlook 2010, there arent any errors or problems at all, just like I said in the post. Nothing happens. Even when I remove all of the other code, nothing happens. It runs like a dream on outlook 2013. The reminder fires and it does everything it is supposed to. There must be some difference between the two release years. Also, the particular code works just fine calling other subroutines when the reminder fires, but does nothing when I run the "daily report"--a subroutine that works just fine on the 2013 machine. Running in a step-by-step manner does nothing. No error.

Comment: Just figured out that my code is not seeing any items in the inbox, even though I have two unread items in the inbox. I have no idea why......continuing the search. Thanks for being such an awesome person Eugene. You are really making this world a better place.